# Need an android code to build background service that can deactivate all the installed apps of a device

Tags: android

Let me know whether is der any background service in android java code available to disable or enable all the installed apps in a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot be "disabled" or "enabled", let alone by another Android app.

You are welcome to implement your own home screen, which can choose to show or not show various launcher icons.